# The Vision API in Xcode 10/Swift doesn't detect anything. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been tinkering with this for a long time and as I'm new to Swift I'm struggling. I am trying to detect a rectangle in the camera's live feed (the eventual goal is to detect when a crossword puzzle is seen) but the included code picks up nothing. I'm looking for the "Rectangle Detected" string in the console but it looks like that code is never reached. Can anyone see why? Here is my ViewController code:

Many thanks in advance.

```
@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

var rootLayer: CALayer! = nil

private lazy var captureSession: AVCaptureSession = {
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    guard let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera) else {
            return session
    }
    session.addInput(input)
    return session
}()
private lazy var cameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)

private let handler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
fileprivate var lastObservation: VNDetectedObjectObservation?

lazy var highlightView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 4
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    /*cameraView.layer.addSublayer(cameraLayer)
    cameraView.addSubview(highlightView)*/
    rootLayer = cameraView.layer
    cameraLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
    rootLayer.insertSublayer(cameraLayer, at: 0)
    cameraView.addSubview(highlightView)

    let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "queue"))
    captureSession.addOutput(output)
    captureSession.startRunning()

}

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer),
        let observation = lastObservation else {
            return
    }
    let request = VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleRectangle)

    do {
        try handler.perform([request], on: pixelBuffer)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

fileprivate func handleRectangle(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let newObservation = request.results?.first as? VNDetectedObjectObservation else {
            return
        }
        self.lastObservation = newObservation
        print("Rectangle Detected")
        var transformedRect = newObservation.boundingBox
        transformedRect.origin.y = 1 - transformedRect.origin.y
        let convertedRect = self.cameraLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: transformedRect)
        self.highlightView.frame = convertedRect
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `fileprivate var lastObservation: VNDetectedObjectObservation?` starts as nil, every call of `captureOutput didOutput` will check if its nil and exit. so it will never be set? `guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer),
        let observation = lastObservation else {
            return
    }` Remove the guard statement, or at least the lastObservation from it and retry

Comment: Huge improvement, i can now see it entering the code section and it's detecting rectangles. The bounding box is wrong but i've seen a lot of people have issues with this where they've handled it incorrectly so i'll work on that. Will the VNDetectRectangleRequest be enough to only fire when it sees a crossword puzzle? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Im not sure tbh, i've not worked with Vision API. I'll post the above comment as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fileprivate var lastObservation: VNDetectedObjectObservation?
```

This property is Optional, so starts as nil.

Every call of `captureOutput didOutput` will check if its nil and exit. so it will never be set. Remove `let observation = lastObservation` from your guard statement and this will fix your initial issue. You may then need to change the logic slightly